# I want to generate line as like attached image using HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to generate line as like attached image using HTML/CSS

[image]

I have tried with two different divs but not generating result as expected.

Any idea on this.

I have tried with two different divs but not generating result as expected.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the purpose of that line (Slider, just decoration, progress bar?)?

Comment: I have tried with two divs with different borders and this is just one line below title of page..nothing else

Comment: And what is the purpose of this? That defines the elements that should be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using **::after** and **content** in the css.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <style>
    #demo {
    position:relative;
    border-bottom:2px solid black;
    }
    #demo:after{
    content:"";
    border:3px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    width:10%;
    left:0;
    bottom:-4px;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
    <p id="demo">This is a paragraph</p>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

This is just an example to show you how it works. You can customize it according to your need.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp

It also gives a test demo on the page, but it might help you with your line on the page, I have used some of their code and they are very helpful.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
<h1>The Main Languages of the Web</h1>

<p>
  HTML is the standard markup language for creating Web pages. HTML
  describes the structure of a Web page, and consists of a series of
  elements. HTML elements tell the browser how to display the content.
</p>

<hr />

<p>
  CSS is a language that describes how HTML elements are to be displayed on
  screen, paper, or in other media. CSS saves a lot of work, because it can
  control the layout of multiple web pages all at once.
</p>

<hr />

<p>
  JavaScript is the programming language of HTML and the Web. JavaScript can
  change HTML content and attribute values. JavaScript can change CSS.
  JavaScript can hide and show HTML elements, and more.
</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what if this is supposed to be a slider? beyond that, that is not close to the picture. A normal block-level element not an replaced element with linear-gradient will be better for a pure design purpose.

Comment: If it needs to be a slider the closest thing I got to was using an (overflow: scroll;) but again that is like a normal scroll slider on a web browser. But that might not solve how the style is for the scroll